# determine frequency of string using grep

Tags: r, frequency

if I have a vector

```
x <- c("ajjss","acdjfkj","auyjyjjksjj")
```

and do:

```
y <- x[grep("jj",x)]
table(y)
```

I get:

```
y
      ajjss auyjyjjksjj 
          1           1
```

However the second string "auyjyjjksjj" should count the substring "jj" twice. How can I change this from a true/false computation, to actually counting the frequency of "jj"?

Also if for each string the frequency of the substring divided by the string's length could be calculated that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this using gregexpr()

```
x <- c("ajjss","acdjfkj","auyjyjjksjj")
freq <- sapply(gregexpr("jj",x),function(x)if(x[[1]]!=-1) length(x) else 0)
df<-data.frame(x,freq)

df
#            x freq
#1       ajjss    1
#2     acdjfkj    0
#3 auyjyjjksjj    2
```

And for the last part of the question, calculating *frequency* / *string length*...

```
df$rate <- df$freq / nchar(as.character(df$x))
```

It is necessary to convert df$x back to a character string because data.frame(x,freq) automatically converts strings to factors unless you specify stringsAsFactors=F.

```
df
#            x freq      rate
#1       ajjss    1 0.2000000
#2     acdjfkj    0 0.0000000
#3 auyjyjjksjj    2 0.1818182
```

Comment: this is excellent thanks. I notice you compute the length of the string - in the data.frame can I call the frequency/length? this would be very useful. thanks.

Comment: oh sorry - what I mean is, can I return for each string the frequency of the substring divided by the string's length?

Comment: sorry - I;m getting Error in nchar(df$x) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Comment: thanks very much, that works and I have added this specification into my question.

Comment: @brucezepplin Since it's been added, I'm going to delete all of my comments here to clean it up.

Comment: @ndoogan Is that really the correct rate though?  for instance if we used your rate calculation on "jj" it would give .5.  I don't know exactly what the OP wants but that doesn't quite seem right.

Comment: @Dason The OP quite specifically asked for this calculation in a note. I may have misunderstood it, but it seemed clear.

Comment: @ndoogan Fair enough - it's more a question for the OP I guess.

Answer (score 8):

You're using the wrong tool. Try `gregexpr`, which will give you the positions where the search string was found (or -1 if not found):

```
> gregexpr("jj", x, fixed = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] 2
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1]  6 10
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2 2
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: the position is actually very useful to me now I think about it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use qdap (though not in base install R):

```
x <- c("ajjss","acdjfkj","auyjyjjksjj")
library(qdap)
termco(x, seq_along(x), "jj")

## > termco(x, seq_along(x), "jj")
##   x word.count         jj
## 1 1          1 1(100.00%)
## 2 2          1          0
## 3 3          1 2(200.00%)
```

Note that the output has frequency and frequency compared to word count (the output is actually a list but prints a pretty output).  To access the frequencies:

```
termco(x, seq_along(x), "jj")$raw

## > termco(x, seq_along(x), "jj")$raw
##   x word.count jj
## 1 1          1  1
## 2 2          1  0
## 3 3          1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple one-liner in `base r` makes use of strsplit and then grepl, and is fairly robust, but will break if it has to count matches like `jjjjjj` as 3 lots of `jj`. The pattern match that makes this possible is from [@JoshOBriens excellent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15575221/1478381):

```
sum( grepl( "jj" , unlist(strsplit( x , "(?<=.)(?=jj)" , perl = TRUE) ) ) )



# Examples....
f<- function(x){
    sum( grepl( "jj" , unlist(strsplit( x , "(?<=.)(?=jj)" , perl = TRUE) ) ) )
    }   

  #3 matches here
  xOP <- c("ajjss","acdjfkj","auyjyjjksjj")
  f(xOP)
  # [1] 3

  #4 here
  x1 <- c("ajjss","acdjfkj", "jj" , "auyjyjjksjj")
  f(x1)
  # [1] 4

  #8 here
  x2 <- c("jjbjj" , "ajjss","acdjfkj", "jj" , "auyjyjjksjj" , "jjbjj")
  f(x2)
  # [1] 8

  #Doesn't work yet with multiple jjjj matches. We want this to also be 8
  x3 <- c("jjjj" , "ajjss","acdjfkj", "jj" , "auyjyjjksjj" , "jjbjj")
  f(x3)
  # [1] 7
```

Comment: this does raise an important point - the accepted answer has solved this. If I had "jjjjjj" I would want to return a frequency of 3. I suppose however this would be a problem if I allowed overlaps in the frequency count giving me a frequency of 5. Thankfully this isn't the case! But thanks for pointing this out.