# How do I count the number of pattern occurrences, if the pattern includes NA, in R?

Tags: r

I have a string of 0's, 1's and NA's like so:

```
string<-c(0,1,1,0,1,1,NA,1,1,0,1,1,NA,1,0,
          0,1,0,1,1,1,NA,1,0,1,NA,1,NA,1,0,1,0,NA,1)
```

I'd like to  count the number of times the PATTERN "1-NA-1" occurs.  In this instance, I would like get the count 5.

I've tried table(string), and trying to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600760/determine-frequency-of-string-using-grep) but nothing seems to work. I would appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: The answers over here may be useful for a generalizable form of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027611/how-to-index-a-vector-sequence-within-a-vector-sequence/33028695 - e.g. - `length(find_pat(c(1,Inf,1),replace(string,is.na(string),Inf)))` with a bit of replacement beforehand

Comment: `length(gregexpr('(?<=1NA1)', paste0(string, collapse = ''), perl = TRUE)[[1]])` returns 5 or slightly shorter `gregexpr('(?<=1, NA, 1)', toString(string), perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# some ugly code, but it seems to work
sum( head(string, -2) == 1 & is.na(head(string[-1],-1)) 
                           & string[-1:-2] == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Not even that ugly - nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
x <- which(is.na(string))
x <- x[!x %in% c(1,length(string))]
length(x[string[x-1] & string[x+1]])
# [1] 5
```

**-- REASONING --**

First, we check which values of `string` are `NA` with `is.na(string)`. Then we find those indices with `which` and store them in `x`.

As @Rick mentions, if the first/last value is `NA` it would lead to problems in our next step. So, we make sure that those are removed (as it shouldn't count anyway).

Next, we want to find the situation where both `string[x-1]` and `string[x+1]` are `1`. In other words, `1 & 1`. Note that `FALSE` and `TRUE` can be evaluated as `0` and `1` respectively. So, if you type `1 == TRUE` you will get `TRUE`. If you type `1 & 1` you will also get `TRUE` back. So, `string[x-1] & string[x+1]` will return `TRUE` when both are `1`, and `FALSE` otherwise. We basically obtain a logical vector, and subset `x` with that vector to get all positions in `x` that satisfy our search. Then we use `length` to determine how many there are.

Comment: Do you mean length(x[string[x-1] & string[x+1]])? @Laterow

Comment: Ah, yes, you want the count.. Added!

Comment: What if the first element of string is NA?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you did there with the T and F?  Can you please expand? @Laterow

Comment: @Rick - `x+1` and `x+2` as indexes?

Comment: Thanks @Rick, added a line that takes care of that. lg929 I'll try to expand.

Comment: there is also the special case where the last value of string is NA