# Match and concatenate characters with grepl() in R

Tags: r, character, concatenation, match

I would like to use the grepl() function to determine whether a vector of characters is matched with a pattern and based on that pattern concatenate characters within the vector. For example:

```
vec <- c("a","b","a","c","a","c","a","b") 
grepl("[a]", vec)
TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I would like the all of the values following the TRUE to be binded together until the next TRUE so that the outcome of this would be a vector that looks like:

```
"ab", "ac", "ac", "ab"
```

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not wedded to `grepl()`:

```
VEC <- paste(vec, collapse="")                # Collapse into single string ...
strsplit(VEC, "(?<=.)(?=a)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]  # ... then split it before each 'a'
# [1] "ab" "ac" "ac" "ab"
```

Comment: (+1) Josh. Brilliant. @SimonO101, for the regexp problem you were facing recently with an answer that was based on Josh's strsplit question, maybe this answer will help?

Comment: Whoa! You just solved my main gripe about `strsplit`; that it always eats the separator, or at least that's what I thought until I saw this answer. Can you add a note about regex terminology for what reference terms to look up in the Table of Contents or Index?

Comment: @DWin -- That was a long-time gripe of mine as well. Half of the answer is to use "look-around assertions" (`(?<=...)`, `(?<!...)`, `(?=...)` and `(?!...)`), which match at the gaps *between* characters. For more on that see the "Perl-like Regular Expressions" section of `?regex`, and [the diagram here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word). Theodore Lytras and I recently figured the other half out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575221/why-does-strsplit-use-positive-lookahead-and-lookbehind-assertion-matches-differ).

Comment: Thanks. Useful discussion. I also thought that the Perl behavior was not as described in `help(regex)`. It seemed in this case that "(?<=a)" should have been enough to split just before the "a"'s

Comment: @DWin -- Exactly. It wasn't until I tried the same regex with `gregexpr()` that I realized, "Oh, duh -- this is an issue specific to `strsplit()`. Theodore Lytras figured out the rest for me ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
groups <- cumsum(grepl("[a]", vec))
# > groups
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
aggregate(vec, by=list(groups=groups), FUN=function(x)paste(x,collapse=""))

#   groups  x
# 1      1 ab
# 2      2 ac
# 3      3 ac
# 4      4 ab
```

Comment: (+1) alternatively: `tapply(vec, groups, paste, collapse="")`