# Split String without losing character- R

Tags: r, strsplit

I have two columns in a much larger dataframe that I am having difficult splitting. I have used `strsplit` in past when I was trying to split using a "space", "," or some other delimiter. The hard part here is I don't want to lose any information AND when I split some parts I will end up with missing information. I would like to end up with four columns in the end. Here's a sample of a couple rows of what I have now.

```
age-gen  surv-camp
45M      1LC
9F       0
12M      1AC
67M      1LC
```

Here is what I would like to ultimately get.

```
age   gen   surv   camp
45    M     1      LC
9     F     0      
12    M     1      AC
67    M     1      LC
```

I've done quite a lot of hunting around on here and have found a number of responses in Java, C++, html etc., but I haven't found anything that explains how to do this in R and when you have missing data.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623147/split-string-without-loss-of-characters?rq=1) about adding a space between values and then just splitting on the space, but I don't see how this would work 1) with missing data, 2) when I don't have consistent numeric or character values in each row.

Comment: You can still use `strsplit()` and save the split values by using `perl`.  What was your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We loop through the columns of 'df1' (`lapply(df1, ..`), create a delimiter after the numeric substring using `sub`, read the `vector` as data.frame with `read.table`, `rbind` the `list` of `data.frames` and change the column names of the output.

```
res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df1, function(x)
      read.table(text=sub("(\\d+)", "\\1,", x), 
          header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
colnames(res) <- scan(text=names(df1), sep=".", what="", quiet = TRUE)
res
#  age gen surv camp
#1  45   M    1   LC
#2   9   F    0     
#3  12   M    1   AC
#4  67   M    1   LC
```

---

Or using `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate(df1, age.gen, into = c("age", "gen"), "(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])", convert= TRUE) %>% 
       separate(surv.camp, into = c("surv", "camp"), "(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])", convert = TRUE)
#  age gen surv camp
#1  45   M    1   LC
#2   9   F    0 <NA>
#3  12   M    1   AC
#4  67   M    1   LC
```

---

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can use `tstrsplit` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) 
    tstrsplit(x, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])", perl=TRUE, 
                        type.convert=TRUE)), recursive = FALSE)]
```

EDIT: Added the `convert = TRUE` in `separate` to change the `type` of columns after the split.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(age.gen = c("45M", "9F", "12M", "67M"), surv.camp = c("1LC", 
 "0", "1AC", "1LC")), .Names = c("age.gen", "surv.camp"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Using `separate` worked out perfectly. Thank you. I haven't been able to adapt the first suggestion and get it to run successful but I will use the logic you wrote out at the beginning and see if I get lucky.

Comment: @SamMarshal  Perhaps your original dataset have some patterns that is not matching with the one you showed.

Comment: Maybe worth showing the data.table way as well, which has the nice `type.convert` feature (not sure if `separate` does): `data.table::tstrsplit(x, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])", perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun that was my thought as well, so I'll work though the logic in each step and see if I can find where things are getting stuck.

Comment: @Frank  Yes `separate` also have that option, but by default it is `FALSE`