# Use strsplit starting at end of string

Tags: r, strsplit

I've currently been using code to split names of individual samples, change part of the sample name, and then rebind the strings together. The code works well when all names are the same length (*ie: names are 8 characters long and it always splits after the first 4 characters*), but when the names are different lengths, the code is no longer effective.

Essentially, individual names are 7 or 8 characters.  The last 4 characters are what's important.
Example with 8 characters: `Samp003A`
Example with 7 characters: `Sam003A`

Is there a way to continue using strsplit to separate my names, but start from the end of the string rather the beginning, to keep the last 4 characters (`003A`)?

**Current code:**

```
> RowList <- as.list(rownames(df1))    
> RowListRes <- strsplit(as.character(RowList), "(?<=.{4})", perl = TRUE)    
> RowListRes.df <- do.call(rbind, RowListRes)    
> RowListRes.df[,1] <- "LY3D"    
> dfnames <- apply(RowListRes.df, 1, paste, collapse="")    
> rownames(df1) <- dfnames
```

It's line 2 that I'm trying hard to edit, so that I can split according to the last 4 characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're a bit mixed up about how to use look-around assertions. The pattern you're using, `"(?<=.{4})"`, is a **look-behind** assertion that says "find me all inter-character spaces that are **preceded** by four characters of any kind", which is not what you really want.

The pattern you actually want, `"(?=.{4}$)"`, is a **look-ahead** assertion that finds the single inter-character space that is **followed** by four characters of any kind **followed by the end of the string**.

There is, unfortunately, an unpleasant twist. For reasons discussed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15575221/980833), `strsplit()` interacts oddly with look-ahead assertions; as a result, the pattern you'll actually need is `"(?<=.)(?=.{4}$)"`. Here's what that looks like in action:

```
x <- c("Samp003A", "Sam003A")
strsplit(x, split="(?<=.)(?=.{4}$)", perl=T)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Samp" "003A"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Sam"  "003A"
```

If all you really want are the final four characters of each entry, maybe just use `substr()`, like this:

```
x <- c("Samp003A", "Sam003A")
substr(x, start=nchar(x)-3, stop=nchar(x))
# [1] "003A" "003A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a substring from the end be simpler?

`stringr::str_sub(as.character(RowList), -4)`

or `stringr::str_sub(as.character(RowList), -4, -2)` to get just the numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is a great option if I were looking to just keep the last 4 characters. But as I'm trying to replace the beginning label with a new one and rebind the new label with the last 4 characters, splitting the string rather than subsetting it seems to be an easier option.