# Sort in R with multiple criteria (alphanumeric)

Tags: r, sorting

```
l <-  c("BC321" , "BC320", "BC100" , "DA124" ,"DA174" ,"DA224", "DA33",  "DA98" )
require('gtools')
mixedsort(l)
"BC100" "BC320" "BC321" "DA33"  "DA98"  "DA124" "DA174" "DA224"
```

But I want 
"DA33"  "DA98"  "DA124" "DA174" "DA224" "BC100" "BC320" "BC321"

Really appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Can you explain your sorting logic here?

Comment: Sorting is on the basis of:
1. Alphabets from Z - > A (descending order)
 and then 2) Within the same block e.g. DA, sorting is based on number (lower to higher--ascending order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
x <- strsplit(l, "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE) ##
v1 = sapply(x, `[[`, 1L)
v2 = as.integer(sapply(x, `[[`, 2L))
l[order(-xtfrm(v1), v2)]
# [1] "DA33"  "DA98"  "DA124" "DA174" "DA224" "BC100" "BC320" "BC321"
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575221/why-does-strsplit-use-positive-lookahead-and-lookbehind-assertion-matches-differ) by Josh O'Brien for the magic happening with `strsplit` (marked with ##).