# Split a string and keep delimiter

Tags: r, string, stringr, strsplit

Lets say I have a string:

```
StringA/StringB/StringC
```

Is there any way I can split this string by the `/` symbol, but keep it in the returned values:

```
StringA
/StringB
/StringC
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with a look-ahead: `(?=/)`

```r
library(stringr)
str_split(str, "(?=/)")

#[[1]]
#[1] "StringA"  "/StringB" "/StringC"
```

Works equally well with `tidyr` separating function:

```r
tidyr::separate_rows(data.frame(str), str, sep = "(?=/)")

#  str        
#1 StringA 
#2 /StringB
#3 /StringC
```

---

With base R's `strsplit`, look-aheads are [less straightforwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575221/why-does-strsplit-use-positive-lookahead-and-lookbehind-assertion-matches-differ), but this works well:

```r
unlist(strsplit(str, "(?<=.)(?=[/])", perl = TRUE))
#[1] "StringA"  "/StringB" "/StringC"
```

And reversely:

```r
unlist(strsplit(str, "(?<=/)", perl = TRUE))
#[1] "StringA/" "StringB/" "StringC"
```

Comment: Thanks! Likewise, how would it work if I wanted it to end with the / instead?

Comment: With a look-behind: `str_split(str, "(?<=/)")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `scan` + `gsub` like below

```
> scan(text = gsub("/", " /", "StringA/StringB/StringC"), what = "")
Read 3 items
[1] "StringA"  "/StringB" "/StringC"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, "/?[^/]+")[[1]]
[1] "StringA"  "/StringB" "/StringC"
```